# How to convert a PDF into a document?

Tags: pdf

Tell me the best Pdf converter. I have been struggling since days to get the best PDF conversion tool but I am not able to find any tool to convert my PDF’s

Comment: Welcome. We want help, but you have to help us a little too :-) Please read [ask]. For instance, what is "a document"? Also, please  note that if what you want to do can be done with your computer's operating system, then you can ask here, but, it seems to me like you probably ought our  to ask on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sister site. Again, welcome. I will post you  an answer (please accept it, if it works, because that will help others who read this question in future) -->

Comment: -->  Have a look at [all of our sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) before posting in future, and include as much detail as you can - help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

> Tell me the best Pdf converter.

Asking for the "best" anything will generally get you downvoted, on most of out sites, as that is a matter of opinion. In this case, though, there is one app that almost everyone would use.

I am using a little guesswork here, since you don't mention your operating system and don't tell us what kind of document you want as output, but ...

A great (and free) tool for docent conversion is [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/).

[This part](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-calibre-support-conversion-to-from) of the Calibre FAQ says

> Calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to every output format.
>
> Input Formats: AZW, AZW3, AZW4, CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, EPUB, FB2, FBZ, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, ***PDF***, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> Output Formats: AZW3, EPUB, ***DOCX***, FB2, HTMLZ, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, PDB, PMLZ, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ, ZIP

I highlighted ***DOCX*** because I guess that you want to convert to an MS Word document. IF I am wrong, it outputs plenty of other "documents".

As a bonus, Calibre ahs a built in viewer, to let you read documents in those formats, ***and*** you can use it to manage your physical eBook reader, such as  Nook, Kindle, etc.

Welcome aboard. I hope that this helped.